# カタカナで表されるようなタグ名を、カタカナと英語、どちらで登録すべきか

Tags: 討議, 日本語, タグ

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローへ投稿する質問にタグを付けるにあたって、
カタカナ、アルファベット、両方で書くことができるタグ名について、どちらを選択すれば良いか迷いました。

たとえば、ツールに関連した質問にタグを付ける場合、タグ名を「ツール」とするか「tool」とするか、というところです。どちらが適切でしょうか？

どちらかを推奨するポリシーがあるのであれば、それが分かるように、タグ入力欄の近くにガイドメッセージを表示していただけると助かるな、と思いました。

Comment: これは手動で「タグシノニム」機能でできます。両方を作成すれば、メタで統一のタグをご教示いただいた際にモデレータが作れます。

Answer (score 13):

今のところはっきりしたポリシーはありません。以下の案はどうでしょう。

1. 固有名詞は、正式表記またはよく使われている表記を優先する

   - 例: iphone
   - なるべく英語版SOでの命名を採用する
2. 普通名詞は、日本語表記を優先する

   - 例: オーサリングツール
   - 日本語話者としての読みやすさを優先するため
3. 固有名詞+普通名詞の場合はそれぞれ上のルールを適用する

   - 例: [英語版のタグ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-animation/info): android-animation → androidアニメーション
4. 違う言語・表記で同じ意味のタグが追加されているのを見つけたら、別名 (シノニム) として登録する。

   - 例: アイフォーン (別名) → iphone (正式名)
   - 例: authoring-tools (別名)  → オーサリングツール (正式名)

---

更新: Yusuke Andoさんの「英語版で確立したタグを継承する」という意見を取り込みました。

Answer (score 5):

英語版のコミュニティと相互リンクできる可能性もあるので、ツールやフレームワーク、言語などで確立したタグがあればそれは継承したらいいのではないでしょうか。