# 正規表現に関するタグシノニムのお願い

Tags: 討議, タグの別名の提案

現在`regex`というタグがありますが、日本語版では`正規表現`タグを使うほうが適切でしょうか？
ちょうど下の記事にタグをつけようとして、この問題にぶつかりました。

[mysql - REGEXPの正規表現について - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2097/regexp%E3%81%AE%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

一応`regex`が存在しているのでこのタグを追加する変更を申請しましたが、

そもそも英語版Stack Overflowで一般的な`regex`をそのまま継承したほうが良いのか、日本語的に分かり易い`正規表現`タグを新設すべきか、ご意見をお聞かせください。

尚、メタで既に行われている似た議論として
[質問: カタカナで表されるようなタグ名を、カタカナと英語、どちらで登録すべきか - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F-%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A%E3%81%A7%E8%A1%A8%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E5%90%8D%E3%82%92-%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A%E3%81%A8%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A1%E3%82%89%E3%81%A7%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8B)があり、そこではカタカナ表現のものに関する話題を扱っています。

---

更新:

タグシノニムという機能があることをお教えいただきました。どなたか権限のある方に`regex`と`正規表現`でのシノニムをお願い致します。

[権限 - タグ シノミムの作成 - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

Comment: どっちかしてから「シノニム」（別名）機能を使って、両方が同じ意味を持つように設定します。それで、どっちでも入力しようとすると、統一のタグになります。

Comment: お教えいただいた内容をもとに、本文を更新しました。

Comment: モデレーター（そして社員）が勝手に作れるので、一番重要なのは、マスターになるタグ（regexか正規表現）はどっちになるべきです。3100の意見を信用していますが、念のためコミュニティからもうちょっともらってから作成します。

Comment: 了解です。以降の議論に委ねます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私の意見では、regexよりも正規表現タグの方が良いと思います。

こういうタグの議論をする時によくGoogle検索の件数を使うようなので、ちょっと挙げたいと思います。

**日本語のページ**を対象に検索した所

- regex(約239,000件)
- 正規表現(約710,000件)

(このやり方は慣れてないので正確かはわからないのですが)となっていて、おそらく日本語圏では正規表現という方が使われているのではないでしょうか？

私の個人的な意見でも、regexと言ったり書いたりする事はあまり無く、正規表現と言ったり書いたりします。

なので、私の意見としては正規表現が良いのではないかという結論になります。

ご参考になれば。

Answer (score 1):

正規表現とregexをシノニムにして正規表現をマスターにしました。