# タグシノニムの提案: "アルゴリズム" (正式名) と "algorithm"

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

[カタカナで表されるようなタグ名を、カタカナと英語、どちらで登録すべきか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F-%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A%E3%81%A7%E8%A1%A8%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E5%90%8D%E3%82%92-%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A%E3%81%A8%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A1%E3%82%89%E3%81%A7%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%81%8B/1385#1385)
にあるように、普通名詞は日本語のタグを作成することが推奨されています。

現在 "[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)" と "[algorithm](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)" の2つのタグが存在しています。
そのため、"[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)" を正式名としたタグシノニムを提案します。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[アルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0)を正式名としました。