# タグ [network] と [ネットワーク] をマージしたい

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

[network](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network) と [ネットワーク](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%8d%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%83%af%e3%83%bc%e3%82%af) がどちらも存在し、使われていることに[気づきました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=suggested)。(また、[array](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) と [配列](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e9%85%8d%e5%88%97) も同様の状況です。)

明らかに同じものを指しているタグなので、マージした上でタグシノニムとしたいのですが、英語と日本語、どちらをマスタータグにすべきでしょうか？　現在シノニム提案されている通り、英語の方をマスターとして良いでしょうか？

正直[自転車置き場の議論](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BD%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E5%87%A1%E4%BF%97%E6%B3%95%E5%89%87)だとは思うのですが、何かご意見があるかもと思い、念の為メタ投稿いたします。

---

関連: [英語タグから日本語タグへのシノニムを作りたい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2542/19110) (←現状英語のままで良いという結論になっています)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[カタカナで表されるようなタグ名を、カタカナと英語、どちらで登録すべきか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1380/3060) での [回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1385/3060) とほぼ同じ案になりますが、「カタカナ英語」「英語版で既に同じタグが存在する」ようなケースなら、私は「**英語表記**」の使用を支持します(今回なら[network](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network)をマスタータグに1票)。

Comment: リンクなさっている[回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1385/19110)には「普通名詞は、日本語表記を優先する」と書かれているので、それに従うと [ネットワーク] がマスタータグになるのではないでしょうか？　（ところで、このメタ投稿のことをすっかり忘れていました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。）

Comment: 回答は結論ではなく、しかも回答２の上位の回答１になるべく英語版SOでの命名を採用するとも書かれているので、マスターをnetworkにするのが良いように僕も思います

Comment: @Чайка さん、「なるべく英語版SOでの命名を採用する」と書いてあるのは、固有名詞を英語のままタグにするときは英語版SOと揃える、という意味だと思います。「network / ネットワーク」は普通名詞です。

Comment: とはいえ私が言っているのは「件の回答と同じ内容ではない」というだけです。理由はともかくとして英語表記を支持するという部分は参考になるご意見です。やはり自転車置き場の議論になっていて、英語表記と日本語表記のどちらの方がより良いかという強い理由は見当たらないですよね。

Comment: 反対意見が無いようでしたので、[network] をマスターとして [ネットワーク] をマージし、同時にシノニムを作成しました✅　[array] / [配列] に対しても同様の操作を行いました。