# タグ "assembly" に対する別名として "アセンブリ言語" の提案

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案, タグの付け替えの提案

[assembly](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly)のタグシノニムとして[アセンブリ言語](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%a2%e3%82%bb%e3%83%b3%e3%83%96%e3%83%aa%e8%a8%80%e8%aa%9e)を提案します。
日本語版では前者の方がマイナーですが、[英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/synonyms)に従うのがいいと思います。

Comment: 特に反対意見が無いようなのでモデレーター権限を使って反映しようかと思います。[assembly]と[アセンブリ言語]で、[assembly]の方をマスターにするということで良いでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu この件、進めましょう。
時間が経っていますので、再度コミュニティで確認が必要そうであれば私が質問を投稿しても構いません。

Comment: @mjy これはどちらがマスターになるのかが分からなかったので止めていたのでした。そこが明らかになれば進められます。このご提案には明確には書かれていなくて、かつ[この投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1385/19110)や[この投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2542/19110)を踏まえると判断しづらく、皆さんどっちになさいたいのかが分からなかったのですよね。

Answer (score 3):

マージに賛成です。現在、どちらをマスターにすればよいか解らない、ということで作業が止まっていますので、この点を補足として提案いたします。

- 処理: 「assembly」をマスターとし、「アセンブリ言語」を別名（タグシノニム）とする
- 理由: 本質問の文面、「assemblyのタグシノニムとしてアセンブリ言語を提案」や「本家に従う」が指すのはこの処理だと思われ、現在これが支持されており反対意見が無い

---

追記(2023-11-22): 上記で作業完了しました。