# タグ名変更と別名の提案: artificial-intelligence → 人工知能

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグの別名の提案, タグの付け替えの提案

[カタカナで表されるようなタグ名を、カタカナと英語、どちらで登録すべきか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380/)にあるように、普通名詞は日本語名が良いとされているため、「人工知能」への変更を提案します。また、英語であっても、一般的にAIと略された言葉の方が多く使われているかと思いますので、その別名をあわせて提案します。

- 現在

  - タグ名: [artificial-intelligence](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence)
  - 別名: (無し)
- 修正案

  - タグ名: [人工知能](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e4%ba%ba%e5%b7%a5%e7%9f%a5%e8%83%bd)
  - 別名: [artificial-intelligence](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence), [ai](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ai)

Comment: +1: 英語版 Stack Overflow でも [ai] が別名になっていました https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artificial-intelligence/synonyms

Comment: 反対意見もないようですので、対応予定としました。念のためもう少し待った後に作業します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

作業を完了しました。

（なお、別名の作成は信用度の高い一般ユーザーによる推奨と、それに対する投票でも行なえます。しかし、現在のユーザー数がこのプロセスには不足がちであることや、既にこのメタ投稿で支持が集っている点を考慮し、モデレーター権限による即時承認としました）